# What do the different attributes do?

Tags: hero-u

In Hero-U, there are a bunch of different attributes that your character has:  Agility, Charm, Climbing, Fitness, Gaming, Luck, Magic, Moxie, Stealth, Throwing, Tool Use, and others.  What are they used for?

Answer (score 1):

Some description from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/roguetoredemption/comments/81ql7z/herou_menus_character_attributes_equipment/)

> Your stamina is your HP, and you can raise this via the **fitness** stat.
>
> **Demerits** are gained by getting caught breaking the rules
>
> **Charm**, **Moxie**, and **Smarts** are usually used for in-game conversation options depending on how you respond.
>
> **Combat** is used for melee, **throwing** is used for throwing daggers, and I think **agility** is for dodging.